# Como evitar conflitos no JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho um sistema onde o cadastro do usuário é feito através de etapas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando o usuário digita o nome, estou querendo que, como acontece aqui no site, o nome apareça automaticamente em uma div ao lado do formulário. Para isso fiz dessa forma:

```
<script>
  var nome = document.querySelector('#nome');
  var paragrafoNome = document.querySelector('#paragrafonome');
  nome.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  paragrafoNome.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><strong>Nome:</strong> <br>" + nome.value + "</div>";
  });
  </script>

<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" class="md-form-control required">

<p id="paragrafonome"></p>
```

Só que eu percebi que esse código está conflitando com o jquery das etapas, pois quando retiro essa linha:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/forms-wizard-validation/js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
```

Funciona normalmente, mas quando deixo essa linha, o preenchimento automático para de funcionar. Tentei colocar o `$.noConflict();` antes do script, mas ele inutilizou as etapas.

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Olá Sam. Certo. Confesso que não conheço muito JQuery. Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Pode ser que esteja conflitando o id

Comment: Certo. Fiz os ajustes e alterei meu post com os ajustes efetuados, mas infelizmente não funciona. Verifiquei se existia conflitos com o id, mas pelo que vi, não existe outro id com o mesmo nome.

Comment: combinado......

Comment: Troca o `keyup`para `input` para ver.

Comment: Se não funcionar, inclua o código dentro desta função: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ COLOQUE O CÓDIGO AQUI });`

Comment: Olá Sam. Infelizmente o conflito continua. Decidi mudar a forma das etapas e permanecer com a solução que você me passou. Obrigado!

Comment: Só para quem quiser aplicar a ideia, usei o step wizard desse link: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/j6rkb Funcionou sem conflitos.